# Post on FB fan page from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api

I want to post FB post on my fan page using ASP.NET. I am able to post on my fan page, but as an admin I can see all the posts. But people who have liked the page are not able to see the posts.
If I manually post anything on the page that particular post will be seen to others.
Please help.
I am using the following code

```
 string app_id = "214545998669814";
        string app_secret = "8cd4e507b943bb34bfb0c33830cbe2a9";
        string scope = "publish_stream,manage_pages,offline_access,publish_actions";

        if (Request["code"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect(string.Format(
                "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}",
                app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope));
        }
        else
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&code={3}&client_secret={4}",
                app_id, Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, scope, Request["code"].ToString(), app_secret);

            HttpWebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();

                foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                {
                    //meh.aspx?token1=steve&token2=jake&...
                    tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                        token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
                }
            }

            string access_token = tokens["access_token"];

            var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);

            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.message = "this is from fan page4.";
            parameters.link = string.Empty;
            parameters.picture = string.Empty; 
            parameters.name = "Article Title";
            parameters.caption = "Caption for the link";

            //446533181408238 is my fan page
            client.Post("/548306908572853/feed", parameters);
```